# spambots and spammy referral links distort analytics data

Tags: hyperlink, google-analytics, analytics

Google Analytics data for my weebly domain site are distorted by spammy links to my site from other, unrelated sites. Not sure whether to call it a spambot or not.

I'm told there's a way to correct for this in Analytics data. How?

I've checked around for answers to this .. most of them seem for those far dweebier than my relatively clueless self. Weebly CS referred me elsewhere for assistance.

Thanks.

Eric

Comment: Did you try referral exclusion list?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. , the referral exclusion list would not (despite its name) exclude any referrers. It would attribute referrals as direct traffic. While this would make the problem invisible it would not solve it.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Yes, I see your point. How about creating filters disallowing specific traffic sources and allowing only a specific hostname?